# unable to use WS.url() in Play app tutorial

Tags: scala, playframework, project-structure

I am doing a tutorial for Play framework with Scala. I am quite early into the tutorial and i am having a problem with ws. In my class `WS` is not recognized although that says to use `WS.url("url-here")` and to import `play.api.libs._` which i have done both. I have also tried using `ws.url("url-here")` as well... and here `ws`is recognized but after that i get a "can't resolve symbol 'url'". Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := """play_hello"""
organization := "x.x"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test,
"com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.9.29",
guice,
ws
)
```

And here is the code for my class:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject

import com.ning.http.client.oauth.{ConsumerKey, RequestToken}
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs._
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.Future

class Application @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends 
AbstractController(cc){
 def tweets = Action.async{
credentials.map { case (consumerKey, requestToken) =>
  WS.url("http://stream.twitter.com")
  Future.successful{
    Ok
  }
}getOrElse{
  Future.successful{
    InternalServerError("Twitter credentials are missing!")
  }
}
}

def credentials: Option[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)] = for{
apiKey <- current.configuration.getString("twitter.apiKey")
apiSecret <- current.configuration.getString("twitter.apiSecret")
token <- current.configuration.getString("twitter.token")
tokenSecret <- current.configuration.getString("twitter.tokenSecret")
}yield (
new ConsumerKey(apiKey, apiSecret),
new RequestToken(token, tokenSecret)
)
}
```

I Figure that most likely this is some type of problem with a dependency conflict. Here is a screenshot of ws related libraries in project [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQkA0.png). I would appreciate any help in finding a solution to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add `ws: WSClient` to the parameters of Application class constructor. Apperently standalone WS object has been removed in more recent versions of ws library.

```
class Application @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, ws: WSClient) extends AbstractController(cc)
```

Now i can use:

```
ws.url("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json")
```

Also according to the documentation on play website if you for some reason can not use an injected WSClient, then you can create an instance of one and use that.